# How do I return missing data when comparing two columns?

Tags: google-sheets

I've read a few similar questions, and I can't seem to find exactly what I'm trying to do.

I have a roster of employees in sheet "Roster" with their names in Column A. In sheet "Hours" I have a list of assigned jobs for tomorrow, with the assigned employee's name also in Column A. I'm trying to add a column of employees from the roster that are NOT in the list of employees on jobs.

The closest I've gotten is with this, on the Hours sheet:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP('Roster'!A2:A, A2:A,1,0))
```

which gives me a list of the entire roster, with the missing ones returning an #N/A error that tells me the missing name when I mouse over it and read the error code. Is there a way to just get a list of the errors? Would I be better off attacking this from a completely different angle?

EDIT: Sanitized example pictures. If what I was trying to do worked, it would return Bob and Jim in this example.

[image: hours]

[image: roster]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going a completely different route. I made a third "Under the Hood" sheet, pulled the two columns into it with queries, ran a match formula down the list and returned "" on errors, then ran a query on Hours to get the names where it had null for the match list.

Comment: Jeff, I'm glad you resolved your issue. If you're satisfied with whatever you've done here (all of which is still unclear from "out here"), please mark your own reply here as "Best Answer." This allows the volunteer contributor community to see at a glance which issues have been fully resolved, so that we can most efficiently use our limited amount of donated time here.

Comment: This answer adds nothing to Stack OverFlow and should be a comment or posted to a personal blog.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're trying to return this list in the "Hours" sheet, you can build off what you had. Try this:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(A2:A,ISERROR(VLOOKUP('Roster'!A2:A, A2:A,1,0))))`

Keep in mind that this formula was written sight-unseen. If it doesn't work as expected, consider sharing a link to a copy of your sheet (or to a sample sheet set up the same way and with enough sanitized but realistic data to illustrate the problem, along with the manually entered result you want in the range where you want it).

Comment: I tested this and it got the right amount of missing names (8) but none of the names were right; each one was included in the job list.

Comment: See the second half of my post. Your images don't add any relevant information for those of us who cannot see the sheet.